# How do I pass a nested hash inside a method?

Tags: ruby

How do I pass a nested hash inside a method? Here is a sample code

```
MONOPOLY_GAME = { 
  deeds: 
  { 
    boardwalk: 
    {  
      price: 400,
      rent: 50
    },
    atlantic: 
    { 
      price: 260, 
      rent: 22 
    },
    baltic:
    {
      price: 60, 
      rent: 4 
    }
  }
}
def rent_for(p)
  return MONOPOLY_GAME[:deeds][:p][:rent]
end

rent_for(:boardwalk)
rent_for(:atlantic)
rent_for(:baltic)
```

Comment: Note: remove the `return` from your method. It's not the problem, but it's not doing anything for your here. The last expression in a method is always the return value.

Comment: Note also that the idiomatic style of writing hashes is the "egyptian braces" (like JSON). It saves lines, it saves indention levels, and it's pretty readable.

Answer (score 5):

Your method seems correct, except that you have to remove the colon from p

```
def rent_for(p)
  MONOPOLY_GAME[:deeds][p][:rent]
end
```